# Convert int from decimal representation of bits to native bits, without using String? (Java)

Tags: java, binary, processing

In the code that I am revising there are Integers and ints that *represent* binary literals by using their decimal digits in the code, e.g.

```
int intDigitsAsBits = 1101;   // integer "representing" 13 to coder
int intDigitsAsBitsB = 1000;  // integer "representing" 8 to coder
```

> Background: I am working with a Java dialect with pre-Java 7 aspects (Processing), such as the unavailability of 0b0000-style binary literals. I am developing native Java 8 libraries in this context -- not Processing code. The interface to Processing is for a community of primarily early code language learners, hence the approximation of binary in a visual form they can understand while typing.

I want to be able to convert these pseudo-binary integer values to their native representation, on the fly, e.g.

```
int intDigitsAsBits = 1101;
int intNative = someUnDecimalMethod(intDigitsAsBits);
System.out.println(intNative);  // "13"
```

I already have a way of doing this using an intermediate conversion to `String` and then converting back with `Integer.parseInt()` using radix=2.

```
int intDigitsAsBits = 1101;
String iString = intDigitsAsBits + "";
int intBinaryValue = Integer.parseInt(iString, 2);
System.out.println(intBinaryValue);  // "13"
```

Is there a Java solution that converts an int or Integer in digits-as-bits format into a native representation -- **without** using String as an intermediate value?

I am interest in particular in efficiency, but any and all solutions welcome.

Comment: If you want efficiency I suggest trying hexadecimal e.g. `0xD` and `0x8` or octal `015` and `010`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you. I'm not sure I understand -- by "trying hexadecimal" do you mean using `Integer.toHexString()` followed by `Integer.parseInt(str, 16)` ?

Comment: No, Java 1.0+ understands octal and hexadecimal numbers in code and these are relatively easy to convert to/from binary

Comment: Ah, yes! Processing doesn't have 0b but does support 0x hex. Unfortunately, as per Background, the requirement is their numbers are encoded as binary-in-decimal ints. The code-learner users can read and write that -- they can't convert hex or octal in their heads. (These are often very early beginners, sometimes young children).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int result = 0;
int i= 0;
while (bits != 0) {
    result |= (bits % 10) << i;
    i++;
    bits /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, to convert directly from digits-as-bits form to native int form you can do the following:

```
int count =0;
int digitsAsBits = 1101;
int result =0;
while(digitsAsBits !=0){
    int lastdigit = digitsAsBits%10;
    result += lastdigit*Math.pow(2, count);
    count++;
    digitsAsBits = digitsAsBits/10;
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- this was very clearly written and solves the problem. I accepted the other answer that was submitted simultaneously because it uses a bit shift rather than invoking `Math.pow(2, count)`.

Comment: @JeremyDouglass , no problem :) ... I agree that the other answer is better because it uses a bit shift ... happy to know that this answer helped too